# Weight cases for cross tabulation, with means

Tags: r, weighted

I like to weight cases to plot graphs in ggplot. I have a specific weight factor for each case, for instance:

```
value weight
2     0.34
5     0.75
6     2.31
```

and so on... Plotting simple grouped bars ("cross tabulation") is easy, I can use the xtabs function:

```
ftab <- round(xtabs(weightBy ~ varCount + varGroup),0)
```

When I want to plot histograms, simple bars or single box plots with weighted cases, I want to keep the distribution, so I use following function to weight the cases:

```
weightby <- function(var, weight) {
  items <- unique(var)
  newvar <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(items)) {
    newcount = round(sum(weight[which(var==items[i])]))
    newvar <- c(newvar, rep(items[i], newcount))
  }
  return (newvar)
}
if (!is.null(weightBy)) {
  variable <- weightby(variable, weightBy)
}
```

However, this function ignores the original case order, the "cases" are now numbered ascending
according to the related categories. But... If I want to plot grouped box plots, I need
a) the weighted variable with weighted counts
b) the weighted variable with weighted groups
c) the weighted means, median and quantiles within each group

How can do I do this? I have the correct weighted cross tabulation, but no weighted means from each sub group, because I cannot use the function shown above for creating tables (because of the lost correct case order).

Any hints are very appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps I should give a visual example. Let's say I want to have box plots of the variable "age", grouped by gender: ![Click here for box plots example image](http://strengejacke.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/box_01.png).
Now if I weight both "age" and "gender" with xtabs(weight ~ age + gender), I have the correct weights, but I need to know the new mean and median value of each group (mean age of female and male persons) - and don't know how to do this.

Comment: why don't you just use the weight aesthetic?

Comment: Ok, the aes(weight=...) helps for grouped box plots and violin plots, thanks a lot! The last thing I miss is calculating the mean for weighted groups. I do this for unweighted data (wb set to 1) with ggplot(mydat, aes(x=group, y=frq, fill=group, weight=wb)) + geom_boxplot() + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", shape=21). When I use weighted data (wb set to certain  weight-factor), the box plots quantiles and medians obviously change, but not the mean point.

Comment: P.S.: for non-grouped box or violin plots it's no problem to get the mean value because I calculate manually the weighted mean without stat_summary function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very unclear what you are asking here.  But the comment at the bottom of your question suggests you want to calculate mean and median value from weighted data.  The easiest way to do this is via the survey package.  You need to create a survey design object with svydesign - you can ignore all the stratification and clustering information and just include the weights - then use functions like svyby() or svyquantile() to calculate whatever you need.

If the question is just about ggplot2(), you can probably get by by just using the weight= aesthetic, unless it doesn't do what I think it does.

Comment: Thanks, Peter, I will check both the package and the weight-aesthetics. What I want is to plot a grouped box plot with weighted data. The original data is not weighted, but I have a weight factor for each case (see example in my post above). I can use xtabs to calculate the weighted cross tabulation of a count and a grouping variable. Or I can use the wtd.mean and wtd.quantile functions from the Hmisc package to calculate weighted means and quantiles - but only for a single variable. What I cannot do right now is to calculate a weighted cross tabulation with weighted mean for each "column"/grp

Comment: I don't know how to use the survey-package. I have tried following: require(survey)
df <- data.frame(cbind(x,y)) # count and group variable
svd <- svydesign(~1,variables=df, weights=gemo$gew_neu)
svymean(~x, svd) # ??? what is the function parameter?

Comment: Ok, I found a mistake in my script. Everything works fine now with the weight-aesthetics of ggplot! Thanks a lot!